# Cron job Issue in raspberry-pi

Tags: python, opencv, cron, raspberry-pi

```
from time import sleep
import datetime
import os
import shutil
import cv2
from filename import opvideo


## Adding New Directory
path= '/home/pi/Desktop/teasr/input-video'+opvideo
os.makedirs(path)
path1= '/home/pi/Desktop/teasr/input-image'+opvideo
os.makedirs(path1)
os.makedirs('/home/pi/Desktop/teasr/output-video'+opvideo)


#######capturing

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('/home/pi/Desktop/teasr/input-video'+opvideo+ '/video.h264',fourcc, 15.0, (640,480))
i=0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        i=i+1
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & i>160:
            cap.release()
            out.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
    else:
        break
`
```

I am looking to run my code after every 10 minutes using cron job. But whenever i my code running it is not capturing video but it is making directory.I am using USB camera for making video. If i am running my code in terminal every thing looks fine and camera is also working. But at cron job it is not working properly.Please help me out to run my full code using cron job.My main purpose is to make video after every 10 mintues when raspberry pi gets switched on. Hoping that someone may help.

Comment: You need to post your code if you want help with it. Note that cronjobs generally don’t have a screen to display things on, so displaying video is going to be tough...

Comment: Here is my code its working properly when i run it normally. But when i am trying Cron-job it is not doing anything except making directories.

Comment: Cronjobs don’t have screens or keyboards so you can’t call `imshow()` or `waitKey()`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i dont want to display video. i only want to make video and save it thats it. But it is not even capturing the video.

Comment: ok but my waitkey() is used to stop video after 10 seconds then how can i handle it ? can u please edit my code and share the updated code with me.

Comment: I don’t speak Python, but get the time at the start of the program. Then inside your loop, get the time on every iteration and subtract the start time, if the difference is greater than 10, quit.

Comment: thanks i just tried the changes u suggested it is working awesome.Thankyou @MarkSetchell

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.

Comment: i just reinstalled my raspberry pi software am not able to run this script using cron tab however it is showing : [ ok ] Starting cron (via systemctl): cron.service.  My command is :sudo /etc/init.d/cron start

Comment: This may be useful to you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413583/2836621